# modify max_length models python django

Tags: python, django, model

I'm working on a python-django project.

If a have a class where one of its attributes have

> max_length=100

how can I change to

> max_length=5000

? for instance...

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem rewriting it to `max_length=5000`?

Comment: is it a character field on that model you're trying to increase the max length for? if it is, go to where that models class in made, and change the field to be django.db.models.CharField(max_length=5000)

Comment: The field is:

motivo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you edit a field on a Model you need to **makemigrations** and **migrate** for changes to take effect in database.  
python manage.py makemigrations <optional_appname(If not provided it affects all apps.)> 
python manage.py migrate <optional_appname>